# How to use "setPress" a Button from an Activity?

Tags: android

I have a fragment that generates buttons like so:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout lLayout;
    MyInterface mInterface;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            final Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tellActivityToPressButton(btn);
                }
            }
            lLayout.addView(btn);
        }
        return lLayout;
    }

    public interface MyInterface {
        void pressButton(Button button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mInterface = (MyInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
        " must implement MyInterface");
        }
    }

    public void tellActivityToPressButton(Button button) {
        mInterface.pressButton(button);
    }
}
```

And my activity is:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.MyInterface {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_activity);
        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, frag);
    }
    public void pressButton(Button button) {
        button.setPressed(true);
    }        
}
```

When I attempt to use this code and run it, the buttons that are created do not remain pressed when I click on them. Why is this? I understand that I could just move the setPressed method into the onClick method for the buttons, but I want it so that I call the setPressed method from the activity like above and the button remains pressed. How can I do this? Or is there any other way to keep a button pressed from the Activity?

Comment: are you trying to make the button appear as if held down? There are other ways like just changing the drawable of the button.

Comment: Is the `pressButton()` ever called?

Comment: Yes I would like the button to appear as if pressed down.
And yes the pressButton() method is called because if I add other things to the method they will work, it's just the setPressed method that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

May be the button is pressed but it just doesnot show up like a "pressed button"
what you can do is add selector to make button look pressed

Put a selector file in your drawable for example

my_button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/light_orange" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
</selector>
```

Use your selector like this

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="how_it_works_button_title"
android:background="@drawable/my_button_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    tellActivityToPressButton(v)
}
```

Try passing `v` instead of `btn` here, since your `btn` reference might be lost by that time. This would mean that you would need to cast your `View` to a `Button` somewhere, but that is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It seems it might just be easier to change the drawable of the button to make it appear pressed, than actually setting it to be pressed.